# JODReports freemarker 'if' with 'and' directive exception

Tags: java, if-statement, report, freemarker

I am using JODReports (http://jodreports.sourceforge.net/) in my project to generate documents. The problem is with 'AND' logical operation in '[#if...]' directives. Example (in '.odt' template):

```
[#if entry1?? AND entry2??]bla bla[/#if]
```

this should write 'bla bla' if 'entry1' and 'entry2' exists and they are not nulls, but while parsing template  i get error:

```
freemarker.core.ParseException: Encountered "AND" at line 4, column 30424 in content.xml.
Was expecting one of:
    ">" ...
    "." ...
    "[" ...
    "(" ...
    "?" ...
    "!" ...
    <TERMINATING_EXCLAM> ...
    "??" ...
    "+" ...
    "-" ...
    "*" ...
    "/" ...
    "%" ...
    "!=" ...
    "=" ...
    "==" ...
    ">=" ...
    <ESCAPED_GTE> ...
    ">" ...
    <ESCAPED_GT> ...
    <LESS_THAN_EQUALS> ...
    <LESS_THAN> ...
    ".." ...
    <AND> ...
    <OR> ...

    at freemarker.core.FMParser.generateParseException(FMParser.java:4697)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.jj_consume_token(FMParser.java:4568)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.If(FMParser.java:1171)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.FreemarkerDirective(FMParser.java:2372)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.Content(FMParser.java:2618)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.OptionalBlock(FMParser.java:2786)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.List(FMParser.java:1257)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.FreemarkerDirective(FMParser.java:2375)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.Content(FMParser.java:2618)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.OptionalBlock(FMParser.java:2786)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.Escape(FMParser.java:2302)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.FreemarkerDirective(FMParser.java:2445)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.Content(FMParser.java:2618)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.OptionalBlock(FMParser.java:2786)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.Root(FMParser.java:2958)
    at freemarker.template.Template.<init>(Template.java:149)
    at freemarker.template.Template.<init>(Template.java:172)...
```

which is weird, because 'AND' is on the list of expected statements. Changing template for something like:

```
    [#if (entry1??) AND (entry2??)]bla bla[/#if]
    [#if entry1?? <AND> entry2??]bla bla[/#if]
    [#if (entry1??) <AND> (entry2??)]bla bla[/#if]
    [#if (entry1)?? AND (entry2)??]bla bla[/#if]
    [#if entry1?? [AND] entry2??]bla bla[/#if]
    [#if (entry1??) [AND] (entry2??)]bla bla[/#if]
```

also doesn't work. Using '&&' or '&' instead of 'AND' gives me error:

```
freemarker.core.ParseException: Encountered ";" at line 4, column 30430 in content.xml.
Was expecting one of:
    ">" ...
    "." ...
    "[" ...
    "(" ...
    "?" ...
    "!" ...
    <TERMINATING_EXCLAM> ...
    "??" ...
    "+" ...
    "-" ...
    "*" ...
    "/" ...
    "%" ...
    "!=" ...
    "=" ...
    "==" ...
    ">=" ...
    <ESCAPED_GTE> ...
    ">" ...
    <ESCAPED_GT> ...
    <LESS_THAN_EQUALS> ...
    <LESS_THAN> ...
    ".." ...
    <AND> ...
    <OR> ...

    at freemarker.core.FMParser.generateParseException(FMParser.java:4697)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.jj_consume_token(FMParser.java:4568)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.If(FMParser.java:1171)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.FreemarkerDirective(FMParser.java:2372)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.Content(FMParser.java:2618)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.OptionalBlock(FMParser.java:2786)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.List(FMParser.java:1257)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.FreemarkerDirective(FMParser.java:2375)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.Content(FMParser.java:2618)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.OptionalBlock(FMParser.java:2786)
    at freemarker.core.FMParser.Escape(FMParser.java:2302)...
```

I can of course write two '[#if]' directives - something like this: `[#if entry1??][#if entry2??]bla bla[/#if][/#if]` - but I don't want do that. Any suggestions?
Thanks, Arek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FreeMarker has no operator like `and` or `AND`, it only has `&&`. So `[#if entry1?? && entry2??]bla bla[/#if]` should work. From the error message you get in that case I assume something (not FreeMarker) has escaped the `&&` to `&amp;&amp;`. That need to be prevented, then it will work.

As of the error messages stating `AND` is supported, that's a raw JavaCC error message, and it just says the token identified as `<AND>` is supported... I recommend using the documentation of FreeMarker when in doubt: http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_logicalop

Comment: Ok, my mistake with 'AND'. So I think there is a problem with .odt templates which probably stores '&' as '&amp;'. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you enter the FreeMarker code directly in the visual document editor (like LibeOffice)? Then it will escape it as it stores it as XML character data. If people enter FreeMarker only like that, then the `TemplateLoader` used by JODReports should un-escape the FreeMarker tags. BTW, interestingly enough, FreeMarker does understand both `<` and `&lt;`, also `>` and `&gt;` as operators, but somehow it forgets to do that with `&amp;`. Needs to be fixed...

Comment: Yes, I use OpenOffice Writer to create templates. For now, I resolved my problem by using `||` instead of `&&` - it is enough at the moment for me :). Yes, I saw in docs, that `&lt;`, `&gt;` are recognized and I'm also suprised that `&amp;` isn't :(. Anyway - thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

If you look into JODReport JUnit test

public void testDirectiveWithSpecialChars() :

https://github.com/hernad/jodreports/blob/master/jodreports/src/test/java/net/sf/jooreports/templates/TextInputTagTest.java

which use this ODT:

https://github.com/hernad/jodreports/blob/master/jodreports/src/test/resources/textinput-directives-special-chars-template.odt

There is same situation and this test is passing correctly.

```
        <text:p text:style-name="Standard">
            <text:text-input text:description="jooscript">[#if (cond1==&apos;pass&apos; &amp;&amp; cond2==&apos;pass&apos;)]</text:text-input>
        </text:p>
        <text:p text:style-name="Standard">All passed!</text:p>
        <text:p text:style-name="Standard">
            <text:text-input text:description="jooscript">[#elseif (cond1==&apos;pass&apos; || cond2==&apos;pass&apos;)]</text:text-input>
        </text:p>
        <text:p text:style-name="Standard">Partly passed!</text:p>
        <text:p text:style-name="Standard">
            <text:text-input text:description="jooscript">[#else]</text:text-input>
        </text:p>
        <text:p text:style-name="Standard">All failed!</text:p>
        <text:p text:style-name="Standard">
            <text:text-input text:description="jooscript">[/#if]</text:text-input>
        </text:p>
```

But when you delete tags:

```
<text:text-input text:description="jooscript"> </text:text-input>
```

The test will fail as you have described.
So for now, solution is to use that tag to encapsulate your code.

Martin

Comment: Here you can find final table of what you can use and when: 
http://mkprogramming.blogspot.sk/2015/05/writing-jodreports-expression-in.html